# WooCommerce - Multiple meta query not working

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, meta-query

Any help on why this multiple meta query is not working is greatly appreciated, both `meta_query` arguments have been tested independently.

I'm looking for bringing Featured products as well as Best Selling(popular) products. Currently this snippet of code is bringing all posts that are `'post_type' => 'product'`, completely ignoring the `'meta_query'`.

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => 10,
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
        array(
            'meta_key' => 'total_sales',
            'orderby' => 'meta_value_num'
        ),
        array(
            'meta_key' => '_featured',
            'meta_value' => 'yes'
        )
    )
);
```

Anybody out there in the wild?

Comment: How is it not working? What do you get, as opposed to what do you expect?

Comment: Its bringing all products. For instance, in my development environment, if I query for `'meta_key' => '_featured'` it shows Product 3, which is a featured product and if I query for `'meta_key' => 'total_sales'` it shows Product 4, which is the best selling product. When I use the code above, it shows the last Product added, which is not featured neither best selling. Assuming that I'm querying for `'posts_per_page' => 1`

Answer (score 1):

`meta_query` format and `orderby` format should be as follows:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'     => 'product',
    'post_status'   => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page'=> 10,
    'orderby'       => 'total_sales',
    'order'         => 'DESC',
    'meta_query'    => array(
        'relation'  => 'OR',
        array(
            'key'       => '_featured',
            'value'     => 'yes',
            'compare'   => '='
        ),
        array(
            'key'       => 'total_sales',
            'value'     => '10',
            'compare'   => '>='
        )
    )
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Instead of `meta_key` and `meta_value` use `key` and `value` with `compare` as mentioned. You can see related documentation of [WP_Meta_Query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Meta_Query) which also works with WP_Query.